# Prevent use of a button before onTouchListener

Tags: java, android

I have a button that does not have a function until an `onTouchListener` is called. As you guys may know, if you press a button before it has a function, the app crashes. I was wondering if it was possible to make the button not clickable until the `onTouchListener` is called? My `.java` file is below.

```
    public class Prompt1 extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt1);

            touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                    redo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            i=1;
                        }
                    });
                    }               
                    return true;
        }
            });

        }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could disable the button until the onTouchListener is registered:

```
myButton.setEnabled(false);
```

And then when you register the listener:

```
myButton.setEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this:

```
public class Prompt1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prompt1);
        Button    button    =    (Button) findViewById(R.id......);
        button.setEnabled(false);
        touchLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){

                 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        i=1;
                    }
                 });
                 return true;
             }               

           }
        });
        button.setEnabled(true);
    }
```